# I cannot give style class to material-menu (Angular 2+)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I would like to set style class to mat-menu. But I have tried everything, and it seems that it doesn't pick it up unless it's in Chrome Inspect.

html

```
 <mat-menu class="matMenuColor" #menu="matMenu">
             <form #logoutForm ngNoForm action="{{logoutUrl}}" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{token}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="goto" value="{{redirectUrl}}">
             </form>
</mat-menu>
```

css

```
.matMenuColor {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Chrome Inspect:

```
.mat-menu-content:not(:empty) {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest solution is to use `:ng-deep`

```
::ng-deep .matMenuColor {
  background: green;
}
```

But you can also try to change it by customize your `theme.scss`

Here you can find the documentation about theming Angular Material
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

UPDATE

If you don't want to use ::ng-deep because it's obsolete try this this:

```
.mat-menu-panel > div.mat-menu-content {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: There was a comment that this will be obsolete?

Answer (score 2):

You can target this way

```
.mat-menu-panel.matMenuColor {
  background: green;
}
```

`.mat-menu-panel` is the class name for `mat-menu` tag which is default.

Answer (score 1):

**::ng-deep is getting obsolete! Dont use it anymore! (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)**

The best way is to create an extra css file like mat-menu.css.

Then you need to import it inside styles.css like:

```
@import 'mat-menu.css';
```

After that you need to import the styles.css in your components css like:

```
@import '../../../styles.css';
```

Inside the mat-menu.css you can style everything you want.

Here is an example of a mat-accordion (this is sass, not css):

```
mat-accordion
    mat-expansion-panel
        border-bottom: 1px $grey-700 solid
        color: $grey-300
        font-size: 18px
        mat-expansion-panel-header
            mat-panel-title
                color: $primary-color
                font-size: 18px
```